# Save calendar event in Outlook

Tags: 2007, calendar, outlook

I am trying to save a calendar event in outlook as a meeting. To elaborate more, I have a calendar which has many upcoming events. I want the users to visit the calendar and register for any event which should get saved in their outlook so that they can be reminded when the event occurs. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up alerts (as emails) for specific item. Would that work for you? Another option is to create a view that would specifically show those events user has subscribed to and have outlook recieve RSS feed for this view. You can read more about [Track updates on SharePoint site.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/track-updates-to-a-sharepoint-site-HA010105445.aspx)

Excellent solution for you would be if you could "connect to outlook" but don't connect to all items, but just the view. OOTB however SharePoint doesn't offer such a feature. There is no ready solution, but there has been some effort to have it somewhat working... involves hacking/coding:

- [Sync list with outlook only with items in current view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231725/sync-list-with-outlook-only-with-items-in-current-view)
- [Sharepoint task list and Outlook sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546811/sharepoint-task-list-and-outlook-sync)

Answer (score 0):

How about the Connect to Outlook feature? This should trigger alerts for events and such.

Comment: Connect to outlook will trigger alerts for all events in the calendar and not specifically for those that I want to.